# xml unix timestamp to mysql timestamp and record mysql 

Tags: mysql, xml, unix-timestamp

My XML:

```
<simpletype type="TURKEY">
<city code="01">
    <telcode>(0 322)</telcode>
    <name>Adana</name>
    <time>1345337940</time>
</city>
<city code="02">
    <telcode>(0 416)</telcode>
    <name>Adıyaman</name>
    <time>1340236800</time>
    </city>
</simpletype>
```

MY Mysql import Code:

```
require_once('db.php');
@mysql_connect(_SERVER,_USER,_PASSWORD);
@mysql_select_db(_DATABASE);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'CityCode.xml' );
$cities = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "city" );
foreach( $cities as $city )
{
$names = $city->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
$codes = $city->getElementsByTagName( "telcode" );
$times = $city->getElementsByTagName ( "time");
$name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
$code = $codes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$time = $times->item(0)->nodeValue;
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO telcode (sehir, name, time) VALUES ('$name' ,'$code'     ,'UNIX_TIMESTAMP ($time') ";
@mysql_query($sql);
```

}

My Question:
My xml source have a unix timestamp and i must use is mysql timeststamp (0000-00-00 00:00:00)
How can i convert $time unix timestamp to mysql timestamp and record mysql db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can convert a UNIX-style timestamp (seconds since 1970 UTC) to a MySQL timestamp with the FROM_UNIXTIME function.

See here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can read a timestamp out into whatever format you like.

`date($format, $timestamp);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php